# django app localhost refused to connect docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to setup my django project with docker. It will have multiple containers one is for code that is server, worker for celery, redis for redis, db for postgres and there is nginx. Every one of them are running without any error but the localhost:8080 is not accessible. I tried accessing localhost:8000 directly and it is still not accessible. Here's all the relevant configuration files of docker.
the `docker-compose.yml` is as:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        restart: always
        image: nginx:1.23-alpine
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - /default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - static_volume:/app/django_static
    server:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        entrypoint: /app/server-entrypoint.sh
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/django_static
        expose:
            - 8000     
        environment:
            DEBUG: "True"
            CELERY_BROKER_URL: "redis://redis:6379/0"
            CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: "redis://redis:6379/0"
            DJANGO_DB: postgresql
            POSTGRES_HOST: db
            POSTGRES_NAME: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    worker:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        entrypoint: /app/worker-entrypoint.sh
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/django_static
        environment:
            DEBUG: "True"
            CELERY_BROKER_URL: "redis://redis:6379/0"
            CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: "redis://redis:6379/0"
            DJANGO_DB: postgresql
            POSTGRES_HOST: db
            POSTGRES_NAME: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
        depends_on:
            - server
            - redis
    redis:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: redis:7.0.5-alpine 
        expose:
            - 6379
    db:
        image: postgres:13.0-alpine
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        expose:
            - 5432
    
volumes:
    static_volume: {}
    postgres_data: {}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Base image
FROM python:3.11.4

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install gunicorn
ADD ./requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app/ 

ADD ./server-entrypoint.sh /app/
ADD ./worker-entrypoint.sh /app/

RUN chmod +x /app/server-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/worker-entrypoint.sh
```

`server-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run database migrations or initialization tasks
echo "Running database migrations..."
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

# Start the development server
echo "Starting Django application..."

gunicorn core.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --threads 4
```

`worker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting celery worker..."
# Run a worker
celery -A core worker --loglevel=info --concurrency 1 -E
```

and lastly the default.conf is as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://server:8000;
    }

    location /django_static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/django_static/;
    }
        
}
```

this is the whole logs of the containers:

```
 docker compose up   
[+] Running 5/5
 ✔ Container celery-redis-django-nginx-1   Created                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container celery-redis-django-db-1      Created                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container celery-redis-django-redis-1   Created                                                                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container celery-redis-django-server-1  Recreated                                                                          0.3s 
 ✔ Container celery-redis-django-worker-1  Recreated                                                                          0.3s 
Attaching to db-1, nginx-1, redis-1, server-1, worker-1
server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx-1   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
redis-1   | 1:C 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.558 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-1   | 1:C 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.559 # Redis version=7.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-1   | 1:C 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.559 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-1   | 1:M 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.559 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis-1   | 1:M 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.562 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-1   | 1:M 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.562 # Server initialized
redis-1   | 1:M 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.562 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-1   | 1:M 26 Jan 2024 09:28:48.562 * Ready to accept connections
nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
db-1      | 
db-1      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db-1      |
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.4
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
nginx-1   | 2024/01/26 09:28:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
db-1      | 2024-01-26 09:28:53.150 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 64-bit
db-1      | 2024-01-26 09:28:53.150 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db-1      | 2024-01-26 09:28:53.150 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db-1      | 2024-01-26 09:28:53.159 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1      | 2024-01-26 09:28:53.170 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-26 08:45:06 UTC
db-1      | 2024-01-26 09:28:53.180 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
worker-1  | Starting celery worker...
server-1 exited with code 0
worker-1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:829: SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
worker-1  | absolutely not recommended!
worker-1  |
worker-1  | Please specify a different user using the --uid option.
worker-1  |
worker-1  | User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
worker-1  |
worker-1  |   warnings.warn(SecurityWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
worker-1  |  
worker-1  |  -------------- celery@8d0c0884d6ae v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
worker-1  | --- ***** -----
worker-1  | -- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.36 2024-01-26 09:29:03
worker-1  | - *** --- * ---
worker-1  | - ** ---------- [config]
worker-1  | - ** ---------- .> app:         core:0x7f97b38c6890
worker-1  | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
worker-1  | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/0
worker-1  | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
worker-1  | -- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
worker-1  | --- ***** -----
worker-1  |  -------------- [queues]
worker-1  |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
worker-1  |
worker-1  |
worker-1  | [tasks]
worker-1  |   . core.celery.debug_task
worker-1  |   . send_email_task
worker-1  |
worker-1  | [2024-01-26 09:29:03,762: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
worker-1  | whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
worker-1  | If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
worker-1  | you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
worker-1  |   warnings.warn(
worker-1  |
worker-1  | [2024-01-26 09:29:03,873: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
worker-1  | [2024-01-26 09:29:03,874: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
worker-1  | whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
worker-1  | If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
worker-1  | you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
worker-1  |   warnings.warn(
worker-1  |
worker-1  | [2024-01-26 09:29:03,878: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
worker-1  | [2024-01-26 09:29:04,887: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
worker-1  | [2024-01-26 09:29:04,901: INFO/MainProcess] celery@8d0c0884d6ae ready.
server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
server-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Can you provide some logs of server and nginx containers, are you sure that containers started normally? And you have services in your compose file two times in example, and extra slash in nginx volumes

Comment: @NikolayPavlin I updated the question with the logs. Also I added gunicorn. and some updates in some of the files

Comment: Your nginx conf is wrong. Youre listening on 80 but your port mapping for nginx on docker-compose is 8080:8080.

You should use 80:80 on port mapping for nginx since your nginx.conf is listening on 80. Also make sure port 80 on the host machine is free, Otherwise change listening port on your nginx.conf to 8080 instead of 80

Comment: both the 8080 and 8000. But I think the issue is with the Dockerfile, as the log, `server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory` suggest it can't find /app/server-entrypoint.sh.

Comment: Just change your nginx.conf to listen on 8080 to match your docker-compose config. Rebuild your nginx docker image and then try again

Comment: I updated the default.conf file to listen on port 8080. and i'm still getting the same issue. `server-1  | exec /app/server-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory`

Comment: You can change only the second `ports:` number to match Nginx's standard configuration, `ports: ['8080:80']`.  The two numbers don't need to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a quick fix. Once you have fixed your port mappings. Remove entrypoint in your docker-compose config for the django app. Add this inplace of entrypont.

```
 command: >
   sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
          python manage.py migrate &&
          gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4"
```

Comment: that did run the server. but i cant access the localhost:8080 or localhost:8000. the log showed it ran: `server-1  | [2024-01-26 10:07:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
server-1  | [2024-01-26 10:07:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9)
server-1  | [2024-01-26 10:07:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: sync`
cant access the provided `http://0.0.0.0:8000` as well

Comment: It must be your nginx configuration. First add port mapping "8000:8000" for the the django app so that you can access it on host machine. Remove expose 8000.

Comment: This inline script seems functionally identical, but harder to read, than the `server-entrypoint.sh` script in the question.  What problem does it fix, and why?

Comment: Removing the expose worked. thanks. But how do i serve the static files?

Comment: You will have to fix your nginx configuration.